# Adding new methods to dataframes

Tags: rust-polars

I see that you can extend the API in Python with custom namespaces, but there is no such functionality in rust it seems.

However, there are optional add-ons for polars like repeat_by. How do I extend the polars data/lazy-frames with my own functions in Rust?

I’d like to add an operation like `df.overlap(df2)` (or `df.genomics.overlap(df2)`)